# How to support custom tiles in large screen in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a dashboard that contains tiles in 3 rows, each row contains 5 tiles. Like the below picture [image]

I am using the below code for tiles:

```
<v-layout row wrap>
  <v-flex xs12 sm8 md4 lg4 xl4 class="lg5-custom pl-0 pb-0 tiles-cursor">
    <v-card flat tile class="d-flex">
      <v-img :src="require('img_url')" aspect-ratio="1" class="grey lighten-2">
      </v-img>
      <div class="content">
        <h3 align="center">A</h3>
      </div>
    </v-card>
  </v-flex>
  <v-flex xs12 sm8 md4 lg4 xl4 class="lg5-custom pl-0 pb-0 tiles-cursor">
    <v-card flat tile class="d-flex">
      <v-img :src="require('img_url')" aspect-ratio="1" class="grey lighten-2">
      </v-img>
      <div class="content">
        <h3 align="center">A</h3>
      </div>
    </v-card>
  </v-flex>
  ... so on
</v-layout>
```

Below is my CSS code to customize the tiles:

```
@media (min-width: 1264px) and (max-width: 1903px) {
    .flex.lg5-custom {
        width: 20%;
        max-width: 20%;
        flex-basis: 20%;
    }
    .flex.lg10-custom {
      width: 40%;
      max-width: 40%;
      flex-basis: 40%;
    }
}
```

Even small screen sometimes 3rd row last tiles don't support.

`.flex.lg10-custom` CSS used for 3rd rows last tile.

I wanted to support this landing page for all screen (especially large screen). Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

So, I have resolved it by using `v-row` and `v-col` instead of `v-flex`. However, all the tiles got small compare to the previous one because the entire row size is `12` and I divided by `5` so, that I can only utilize only `10`, not `12`. I had to leave `1` from left and `1` from the right to make it `center`. Below is my code:

```html
<v-container fluid>
  <v-row justify="center">
    <v-col cols="2" class="pb-1 pt-1 pl-1 pr-1">
      <v-card elevation="23" class="secondary ml-0 mr-0 mt-0 mb-0 change-mouse-pointer">
      <v-img :src="require('img_url')" aspect-ratio="1" class="grey lighten-2">
      </v-img>
      <div class="content">
        <h3 align="center">A</h3>
      </div>
    </v-card>
  </v-col>
  <v-col cols="2" class="pb-1 pt-1 pl-1 pr-1">
      <v-card elevation="23" class="secondary ml-0 mr-0 mt-0 mb-0 change-mouse-pointer">
      <v-img :src="require('img_url')" aspect-ratio="1" class="grey lighten-2">
      </v-img>
      <div class="content">
        <h3 align="center">A</h3>
      </div>
    </v-card>
  </v-col>
  ... so on
 </v-row>
.... last row last col
<v-row justify="center">
... first 3 will be the same as before

  <v-col cols="4" class="pb-1 pt-1 pl-1 pr-1">
      <v-card elevation="23" class="secondary d-flex" height="50%">
      <v-img :src="require('img_url')" aspect-ratio="1" class="grey lighten-2">
      </v-img>
      <div class="content">
        <h3 align="center">A</h3>
      </div>
    </v-card>
  </v-col>
 </v-row>
</v-container>
```

If anyone wants the full solution, please comment below.